# Is it bad practice for a model to call itself within itself?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here's an example, using Eloquent in Laravel.

Let's say I'm working on a CMS.

- the controller takes the route and looks up the page via the route.
- the model provides a static function that uses the route to figure out the id of the row it's looking for
- the model then **uses itself** to perform the database query and returns the result

**Example Controller Code:**

```
Route::get('(.*)', function($route)
{
    $page = Page::load_by_route($route);
});
```

**Example Model Code:**

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

    public static function load_by_route($route)
    {
        // Explode the route and trace to find the actual id of the row we need.
        // ... some lines of code to accomplish it...

        // Use the $id we discovered to perform the actual query
        $page = Page::find($id)->first();

        return $page;
    }
}
```

Before you ask "Why can't you just use *Page::where('route', '=', $route)->first()* in the first place: I'm not wondering 'how to do' this example. I'm just wondering if it is it bad to to be using Page:: inside the page model?

Comment: why not? but you can use `self` instead of class name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but convention says to use `self` to reference the current class:

```
$page = self::find($id)->first();
```

Comment: I actually use `static::methodName()` within the class, but don't know the difference

Comment: @MirkoAkkov check for late static binding in php 5.3+ to understand the difference between `static` and `self`

Comment: Thanks Marko D. I just started search google for a `static vs self` combination :)