# Call model from within itself

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I have a model in laravel and need to call it within itself to check if there already are entries. It's for a generic (polymorphic) case where I don't want to do it in the controller.

This works just fine:

```
$check = self
    ::where('foreign_id',$this->attributes['foreign_id'])
    ->where('foreign_type', $this->attributes['foreign_type'])
    ->where('category', $this->attributes['category'])
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->first()
;
```

Now I can access the properties with $check->id for example.

But I can't do something like this:

```
$check = self
    ::where('foreign_id',$this->attributes['foreign_id'])
    ->where('foreign_type', $this->attributes['foreign_type'])
    ->where('category', $this->attributes['category'])
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
;

if($this->isUser()) $check->where('user_id',$this->attributes['user_id']);
else $check->where('guest_ip',$this->attributes['guest_ip']);

$check->first();
```

It's not adding the new wheres within the if statement to the query.

I thought self is the way to go according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15282754/1233206

In my case however it seems to be not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this inside a static function?

Comment: No it's not. It's a public function. I make something like $model = new Model; and then I pass some things to it that I'm - inside the model - accessing with $this->attributes['some_attr']. Then I call it like $model->check()

Comment: Okay. In the code you posted you're not doing anything with the result of `$check->first()`. Try `$check = $check->first()`

Comment: I'm trying to make something like $check->id to get the ID but I'm getting "property not defined". But $check->count() is outputting me one result and that's absolutely correct. Edit: I'll try your edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$check->first()` will run a query and **return** the result. The `$check` variable itself will not be changed. So if you try this:

```
$check->first();
if($check->id == 'something'){}
```

It won't work because you're interacting with the query builder instance. You have to do this:

```
$check = $check->first();
if($check->id == 'something'){}
```

Comment: @sleepless: I'd add here that since the name `$check` is two different things (the original value and the result from `first()`), you should give them different names. IDEs (e.g. NetBeans) complain at this sort of reassignment, since it makes code harder to follow.

Comment: No probs @sleepless. If you only use this value once, I expect you can merge it, to avoid the saving of the intermediate value: `$check->first()->id`.

Comment: @halfer: Nice thought. But actually I'm using it in a big if-statemant multiple times with different values - not only the ID. It worked all fine until I added the if($this->isUser()) thing and still, the answer was so simple :)